# Create random, unique variable names for objects

Tags: python, variables, random, unique, names

I'm playing around with Python and any programming language for the first time, so please bear with me. I started an online class two weeks ago, but try to develop a small game at the side to learn faster (and have fun). It's a text adventure, but is shall have random encounters and fights with enemies that have random equipment that the players can then loot.

This is my problem: If I create random objects/weapons for my random encounter, I need to make sure that the object has a unique name. The way the level is designed there could in theory be an infinite number of objects (it can be open ended, with encounters just popping up).

This is my approach so far

```
class Item_NPCs: #create objects for NPCs

    def__init__(self, item_type, item_number):
    # e.g. item_type 1 = weapons, item_type2 = potions, etc.

        if item_type == 1 and item number == 1:
             self.property1 = 5
             self.property2 = 4

        if item_type == 1 and item_number ==2:

       # etc. :)

def prepare_encounter(): 

    inventory_NPC = [] # empty list for stuff the NPC carries around

    XXX = Class_Item(item_type, item_number) # I might randomize the arguments.
```

What is important is that I want "XXX" to be unique and random, so that no object exists more than once and can later be put into the player's inventory.

How to do that?

Joe

Comment: Important: your **values** must be unique, not your variables. Variables are placeholders in an algorithm. Your algorithm cannot function if its placeholders are an undefined mess. If you need to hold *several values*, even random ones, use a `list` or `dict`.

Comment: @deceze is right, if you need a random __name__ for the object you should consider passing it to the constructor of `Class_Item` and assign it to an attribute of the `Class_Item` instance.

Comment: Or if the name is always on the form "Item X" you could generate that name in the constructor by having the class keep tabs of the number of created instances.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need it to be random ? You could simply use a list, and append every new object to the list, with its index being its unique identifier :

```
items = []
items.append( Class_Item(item_type, item_number) )
```

But if you really need random identifier, maybe you can use a dictionary :

```
items = dict()
items[random_id] = Class_Item(item_type, item_number)
```

This requires random_id to be hashable (but it should be if it is a number or a string).

Comment: OK, this is interesting, because it hints at that I'm getting something wrong. I expected that it will be a problem to create two identical objects under the same variable name and then try to treat this as two different objects. If I understand you correctly, being in the same list on different indices is enough two make python treat this thing a two different objects? If so, I don't need random names. I thought it would be necessary. --> Sorry can't test anything now. At work.

Comment: You can create objects with different names, but I don't think that is what you really want. What you actually want is ensembles of objects : the player's objects, the enemy's objects, etc... This gives structure to your program (and avoid a mess of variables, like deceze said), but it also gives you much more potent functionality to manipulate the objects. For example, with a `player_items` list/dict, you can show to the player his items with a simple loop : `for item in player_items: print(item)`, and at the end of the fight, you can add the loot : `player_items.extend(enemy_items)`.

Comment: I love the extend thing. I might give the player the choice what to loot though. .... btw: This is what I got so far as module for inventory and objects: https://trinket.io/library/trinkets/1210c14e8c ... I asked because now I want to add the enctounter system and believed I need the different variable names. But ... the posts here hint at that not being the case. Looking forward to experiment.

Comment: Choosing loot can be done in a similar way. You can print the enemy items and their id number : `for id, item in enumerate(enemy_items): print(id, item)`, get from the player the list of id of the objects he wants with `chosen_loot = raw_input()`, then add those to the player items : `player_items.extend([enemy_items[id] for id in chosen_loot])`. What I want to emphasis here is that using data structures like `list`, `dict`, `set`, etc... is the correct way to handle large collections of objects and allows you to do things in a simpler and clearer way.

Comment: From what I see in your code, your approach is very OOP. I think there are things you could do more efficiently with Data Structures. If it's your first time programming, I am not sure OOP is the best way to start. It can easily go the wrong way : for example, you made an `Item` class, then you identify what kind of object it is by an `item_type` field, this seems wrong to me, you don't use polymorphism, and end up with a lot of `if-elif`. Also before creating your own data structures, imo it's good to understand how to use the native data structures of the language.

Comment: Yeah, but it's part of the purpose of the thing to bloody my nose. When I started this I didn't even know there is something like "name space". I realized after some research when I couldn't change list items in the object methods. The idea is that every level of the game gets more sophisticated. I get an idea what I want to do and try to do it withe the means I have or can access with the means I have. It's bound to be messy. I agree that I risk getting into bad habbits though.  Thanks for the feedback! I will look up what OOP is now :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why others haven't thought of this:

```
yourvariableName = randint(0,1000)
exec("var_%s = 'value'" % yourVariableName)
```

I just thought of it myself. I hope it helps you.

A downside is you can't just do this:

```
print(var_yourVariableName)
```

you can only do this:

```
exec("print(var_%s)" % yourVariableName)
```

But you can probably circumvent this one way or another. Leave a comment if you manage to figure it out.

One more downside — if used in certain ways, it could be very insecure (as we are using `exec`), so make sure to cover any holes!